# Design Patterns in C++ with Qt 4

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

I have been looking for tutorials or books about design patterns in qt and so far i have found one book, "Introduction to Design Patterns in C++ with Qt 4".Has anyone read this book?.Also,where can i read about design patterns implemented in qt?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Introduction to Design Patterns in C++ with Qt 4* uses Qt 4.1 to demonstrate its concepts. So much has changed since Qt 4.1 that I suggest first learning about design patterns, and then learning Qt (separately). Once you understand design patterns, you can browse the Qt source code and be able to recognize the patterns yourself.

[Design patterns - Elements of reusable object oriented software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) is a great book on design patterns with examples in C++.

Comment: +1 still on my bookshelf and I still crack it open from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of design patterns is they solve common problems in programming not just a particular framework or language. QT uses them extensively so might find this little video introduction interesting http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzgtqJoD1PE